# How to customize 'Order Total Report' (REPORTS > Customers > Order Total) in magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2, custom-reports

I need to achieve this:

> In 'Order Total Report' (REPORTS > Customers > Order Total) add new
>   columns, 'ID', 'Affiliate ID', 'Total BVP Purchase'.

**'ID' ==> will display Customer ID**

**'Affiliate ID'  ==> will display Custom customer attribute value stored in 'affiliate_id'.**

‘BVP Total'  ==> will display total successful purchase done in BVP by particular customer during that period. Product’s BVP value is stored in custom product attribute ‘product_bvp’. Kindly check screenshot attached for BVP. **(Note.Price & BVP are 2 different entities. Currently it's calculating Total price. Similarly I want
Total BVP)**.

Upon exporting report to CSV it should display above extra 3 columns
with default columns.

[image]

Comment: any solution for this?